# Tomcat 10 Maven Deployment To jar file

Tags: java, tomcat

I try to use Tomcat10 based on the maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.20</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

The problem is, there is deployed jar file at the end; just the war file. Is there any solution / plugin / configuration to let tomcat10 deploy the server as a jar file?

Comment: If you want to deploy on Tomcat, you typically rather have servlet-api and others as dependencies, not tomcat itself. And you build a WAR file. Is there a reason why you are using this dependency?

Comment: The problem is not clear, is an attempt being made to make an uber Tomcat jar and run it from somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you misunderstand [Jakarta Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Servlet) technology (formerly Java Servlet).

One of the principal goals of Servlets is to free you from being tied to any one particular vendor. So you write your Servlet according to the [Jakarta Servlet API](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/). Later you deploy your servlet as a WAR file to any Servlet container from any vendor. Your target deployment server vendor should be irrelevant at compile time.

So your project should include as a dependency the Servlet API, not Tomcat specifically. You configure that dependency for use only while coding, not for inclusion in your final product. At deployment time, the particular Servlet container will provide its own copy of the Servlet API, along with its own implementation of that API.

For deploying to [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/) 10.0.x, your project’s dependency should be [Jakarta Servlet 5.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/). See the [*Which version?*](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) page of the Tomcat documentation site.

Some people use an alternative deployment strategy. Those folks choose to embed a particular Servlet container along with their web app, packaged as a [JAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) rather than [WAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)). Deployment is then done as a service on its own, rather than plugging into an existing Servlet container as described above.

If your goal is to go with this second deployment strategy, I highly recommend using a framework aimed at that purpose rather than doing your own packaging. [*Spring Boot*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot) is one of the most popular such frameworks.